# Emacs 'helm-M-x' and 'helm-multi-files' too slow

Tags: emacs

I'm new to Emacs and I want to use it in work.
I studied [helm](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html) and [helm+projectile](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html) tutorials and tried them out.

The version of Emacs I use is 24.3.1.
I used the configuration as described there.

After a couple of minutes of work the popping up of 'helm-M-x' and 'helm-multi-files' buffers becomes too slow (up to five seconds) and the CPU load at that jumps up to 100% according to htop. After restarting of Emacs the problem goes away but only for a short while.

The problem seems not to arise if I dont't call 'helm-projectile-switch-project'.

I really like Emacs now, but this problem makes it impossible to use it. Googling did not give any results, as if I'm the only one experiencing this problem.

Please help